# image.open opens the same image twice and advide for creating loop

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm basically just starting to write in python, so excuse me if I'm missing something obvious. I'm trying to build a quick and very simple tool that combines two images in one while leaving a blank grey space with the specified color between them. Now, when I run this code, I basically get the result that I want, however, for some reason it doesn't contain the two different images, but the same image, namely the one I called "img", twice. This is what my code looks like:

For the problem:

```
img = Image.open("/Users/someone/Documents/Stimuli/1_5_1_n1.bmp")
img = img.resize((1280, 1280))
img1 = Image.open("/Users/someone/Documents/Stimuli/2_7_1_n1.bmp")
img1 = img.resize((1280, 1280))
bi = Image.new("RGBA", (2760, 1280), ("#808080"))
bi.paste(img, (0,0,1280,1280))
bi.paste(img1, (1480,0,2760,1280))
bi.show()
```

Comment: Possible typo: try changing `img1 = img.resize((1280, 1280))` to `img1 = img1.resize((1280, 1280))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img1 = img.resize((1280, 1280))
```

Presumably you meant `img1.resize(...)`.